# ADO.NET - SQL bit value "1" still being read as "false" by DataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

If I run my stored proc from SSMS, I can clearly see a `1` in the column in question (which should return `true` in ADO), but when in my midtier, the `DataReader` always returns `false`.   I feared this may be because I am casting the value to a `bit` in my `SELECT` statement, but if I change the `CASE` statement to just be `CAST(1 AS BIT)` the `DataReader` correctly reads everything as `true`, so it's not the casting.  [hat tip to @MikhailLobanov for this]

Here's my SQL script:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN receiptid IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS BIT)
    ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT)
END [WasAdjusted]
FROM dbo.MyTable

UNION ALL

SELECT CONVERT(BIT, 0) [WasAdjusted]
FROM dbo.MySecondTable
```

Then here's my ADO.NET C# code:

```
Func<IDataRecord, ResponseModel> searchReader = delegate (IDataRecord record)
{
    var model = new ResponseModel();
    model.BooleanProperty = record.GetBoolean(0);    
    return model;
};
```

Someone asked for surrounding code, so here is my `DataReader`:

```
protected static List<TReturnType> ExecuteReader<TReturnType>(string connectionString, string storedProcName, Func<IDataRecord, TReturnType> delegateFunction, List<SqlParameter> collection = null)
{
    List<TReturnType> results = null;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connect.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, connect);
            command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (collection != null)
            {
                collection.ForEach(x => command.Parameters.Add(x));
            }

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (results == null)
                    {
                        results = new List<TReturnType>();
                    }

                    results.Add(delegateFunction((IDataRecord)reader));
                }

                reader.Close();
            }

            connect.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Then you call this like so:

```
return ExecuteReader(_connectionString, "dbo.NameOfStoredProc", searchReader, sqlParams);
```

What am I missing?  Thanks.

Edit 2017-04-25: Looks like someone else might be having same issue: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data/issues/12

Comment: Might be you need to name your column (give an alias to the column)?

Comment: @Shnugo the name of my column (FWIW) is `WasAdjusted`.  I've tried doing `record.GetBoolean(record.GetOrdinal("WasAdjusted"))`, but that gives me the same result.  I'll update my question to show.

Comment: why should you cast some value as bit? you just need two different values, why not just return some thing like 'T'/'F', and record.GetString(0)

Comment: @lei-yang that's not a bad hack; I might have to do that if there's no other solution. If you don't specifically cast them as `bit` SQL automatically assumes they are integer `int` values

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Returns correctly in a simple sample app I threw together. Are you using the SqlClient provider, or something like OleDb/Odbc? What version of .Net? Can you show some of the surrounding code?

Comment: Try `SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT) AS WasAdjusted` It's much easier to debug

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn added some surrounding code

Comment: @MikhailLobanov thank you, that was a great idea! I did that, and now .NET reads them all as `true`.  -_- so it's not the casting that is the problem.

Comment: Based on the info with @Mikhail it seems like the case expression might not be coming back to ADO as a bit type. Try moving the cast outside of that expression: `CAST(CASE WHEN receipts IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) [WasAdjusted]`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn argh! Tried moving the `CAST` outside, and that didn't work either. I was optimistic about that one

Comment: It seems problem with your data: `receiptid IS NULL` for ALL records. Is it possible? Next qury to try: `SELECT CASE
    WHEN receiptid IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
    ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT)
END [WasAdjusted]` There are always `CAST(1 AS BIT)` - to test CASE clause

Comment: @MikhailLobanov `SELECT CASE WHEN receiptid IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END` correctly renders everything as `true` as I would have hoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the user executing the stored procedure has the same/equal permissions. It's possible that the app user (executing the `IDataReader`) might have different permissions than the account you personally are using to log into SSMS, in which case the same stored proc would provide two different result sets.

Comment: I have the same problem. I use the same login account in SSMS as in Visual studio and the results are different :/

Answer (score 0):

The `IDataRecord.GetBoolean` method expects that the value is already a boolean value. It will not attempt to convert it. You can use the following code to get the boolean value:
`Convert.ToBoolean(record.GetValue(record.GetOrdinal("WasAdjusted")))`

Comment: The problem is `record.GetValue(record.GetOrdinal("WasAdjusted"))` returns `false` when it should be `true`, not that it cannot recognize a boolean.